# Tilde is not a shorthand for the /home/pi directory

Tags: filesystem

When I write

```
cd ~
```

I get to the `/var/www` directory.

I would like to get to my home directory at `/home/pi` when I write `cd ~`.

Some may argue that an alias would be the solution, but it seems like the RPi thinks that the `/var/www` is the actual home directory, because it puts all the configuration files in there.

I have the Apache web server installed, its public directory is in the `/var/www` directory.

How do I change the "tilde" directory to be `/home/pi` instead of `/var/www`?

Comment: if you run "whoami" are you actually the pi user?

Comment: Also, what is the result of `echo $HOME` and/or `cat /etc/passwd | grep $(whoami)`?

Comment: @rob When i type in `whoami` I get `pi`
Wilf, when I type in `echo $HOME` I get `/var/www`.
And when I type in `cat /etc/passwd | grep $(whoami)` I get
`pi:x:1000:1000:,,,:/var/www:/bin/bash`.

By somehow I have made the `/var/www` directory to my home directory. How can I change it back to `/home/pi`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `root`, edit `/etc/passwd`.

The file will be a long list of users (system and real).  Towards the bottom, you should see your username.  The last column but one, will be your home directory.  Here's mine:-

```
gareth:x:1000:1000:Gareth Williams:/home/gareth:/bin/bash
```

Where it says `/home/gareth` above, it (probably) says `/var/www` on yours.

Also, your home directory must exist on the computer. First check that you have a home directory:-

```
$ls /home
gareth
$
```

If your username is there (`gareth` in my case), than all is well, otherwise make the directory using:-

```
$/sbin/mkhomedir_helper gareth
```

Finally, log out and in and everything should be working.